# Running out of memory during dplyr installation

Tags: r, dplyr

```
g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include -DCOMPILING_DPLYR  
-I"/home/ubuntu/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1/Rcpp/include" -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/BH/include"   -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat - Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c dplyr.cpp -o dplyr.o
virtual memory exhausted: Cannot allocate memory
make: *** [dplyr.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘dplyr’
* removing ‘/home/ubuntu/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1/dplyr’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmphQUe9d/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("dplyr") :
  installation of package ‘dplyr’ had non-zero exit status
```

Is this simply saying I don't have enough RAM to compile 'dplyr'? Are there any workarounds?

Comment: Yes, give it more than the 512mb or whatever you have there.  Swapfiles can help some. Real memory is better.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel How exactly do I do that? I'm using an Amazon EC2 instance for the first time so I'm a bit lost.

Comment: [How to add a swap file](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-add-a-swap-file-howto/). You might want to try to use a larger instance type than t2.micro (assuming you're using the free tier).